# Is it possible to receive notification using UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wordpress, uiwebview

I know that the title is not clear, but I'll explain it here.
So I created an IOS App using swift and UIWebView, it's a simple app that using a website (blog). So I just want to know if it's possible to receive a notification in the iphone when I post a new article in my blog.
PS: I created the blog using WordPress.

This is my app :
 [image]

Comment: Yes, but you have to implement it in swift/Objective-c. But Apple might reject you app if it is just a wrapper for a website.

Comment: No they accepted it, you can find it in the appstore. How can I do please ? do you have a tutorial ? Thanx

Comment: Asking for tutorial is offtopic for stackoverflow, but just follow the Apple documentation for push notifications.

Comment: @MansSalah-Eddi, Did you solved your problem? are you able to receive push notifications on UIWebView?

Comment: @MansSalah-Eddi can u share u solution? notifications on the web maybe works? thanks